# How to monitor WAN traffic?

Tags: networking, router, cable-modem, wan, traffic

I'm looking for a way to monitor the WAN traffic for my Arris Touchstone cable modem/router mainly to check the speed. The modem's web GUI doesn't offer any option of that sorts and I was looking for a third party firmware like DD-WRT for it but I couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to accomplish this on Windows 7 for routers that don't offer that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several software tools that can do what you want.  [This link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/monitor-internet-usage/) mentions five free ones:

1. [NetWorx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/)

Once you install NetWorx, it will track all your Internet usage with an icon on the taskbar.

2. [BitMeter 2](http://bitmeter-2.lastdownload.com/)

This program comes with a desktop widget meter graph of your download and upload speeds.

3. [NetSpeedMonitor](http://www.floriangilles.com/software/netspeedmonitor/)

This program permanently sits on your taskbar showing upload and download speeds.

4. [Cucusoft Net Guard](http://www.cucusoft.com/netguard.aspx)

This program has a very clean user interface that is easy to understand.

5. [ISP Monitor](http://ispmonitor.be/software/)

ISP Monitor is a lightweight program to easily track your daily or monthly internet usages.

Comment: External links can disappear, in which case your answer would have no value.  Please use the link only for attribution and further information, and add the essential information to your question.  In this case, the essential information is other links, but it would be unlikely to lose all of them, and the products could be looked up from the names.

Comment: That is logical. I will do so.